# Symfony2 create a URL by replacing a router pattern vaiable from the current URL (How to edit current URL?)

Tags: php, symfony, routes, symfony-2.3

I want to replace the `emailtemplates` router to `contactpoints` from the following URL

```
  http://localhost/app_dev.php/config/workflow/configset-72/partner_site/emailtemplates
```

My **routing pattern** is: **/config/workflow/configset-{configSetId}/partner_site/{steps}**

I am currently using following code to generate a URL. But in this way I have to redefine the `confgSetId`, so, **is there any other way to replace only** "`steps`" (`emailtemplates` with `contactpoints`) route pattern?

```
        $routes = new RouteCollection();
        $routes->add('deploy_config', new Route('/config/workflow/configset-{configSetId}/partner_site/{steps}'));
        $context = new RequestContext();
        $context->fromRequest($this->getRequest());
        $urlGenerator = new UrlGenerator($routes, $context);
        $r = $urlGenerator->generate('deploy_config', array('configSetId' => $this->getConfigSet()->getId(), 'steps' => 'contactpoints'));
```

If I ask it simply I want to know:
**How to edit current URL inside a controller in Symfony2?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redirect to the new url like this assuming you are inside an action:

```
return $this->redirect($r);
```

Here is the relating part in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting

To get the current route use this:

```
$currentRoute = $request->attributes->get('_route');
$currentUrl = $this->get('router')->generate($currentRoute, array(), true);
```

Therefore you need to implement the Request in the action:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
...
function someAction(Request $request){
```

Comment: I want to edit the current URL to be something else and to print that  in a twig template